WordPress - Optimize the Meta Query for 3 meta keys at a time
Records in post_meta as follow:



post_id
key
value




1
price
10


1
price_to
5000


2
price_type
'POA'


3
price
12000


3
price_to
17000


4
price
1200


4
price_to
8000


5
price_type
'POA'



Code Snippet
<?php
$price_from = '20';
$price_to = '700';

$meta_query_price[] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'    =>  $price_from,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price_to',
            'value'    =>  $price_to,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'  => '>='
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'price_type',
        'value'    =>  'POA',
        'type'    =>  'value',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ),
);

Output



post_id
key
value




1
price
10


1
price_to
5000


2
price_type
'POA'


5
price_type
'POA'



Above code is executed perfectly issue is when I add price_type to the meta_query to extend data it will cause the speed issue.
The result come perfect but time will be very high.

So, is there any tricks to do this kind of query in WordPress?


Have you checked the joins are correctly added echo $wpdb->last_query with this?

Your placement of meta_query was wrong. That's why the you not able to get proper output.
Try below snippet
<?php
$meta_query_price[] = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'price_type',
        'value'    =>  'POA',
        'type'    =>  'value',
        'compare'  => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'    =>  $price_from,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '<='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price_to',
            'value'    =>  $price_to,
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare'  => '>='
        ),
    ),
);

Condition 1: Price Type Check:

This condition checks if the meta key price_type has a value of POA.
The compare parameter is set to LIKE, which allows for partial matches.

Condition 2: Price Range Check:

This condition is nested within an AND relation, meaning both sub-conditions must be met for this block to return true.
Sub-condition 1:

Checks if the price is less than or equal to $price_from (20).


Sub-condition 2:

Checks if the price_to is greater than or equal to $price_to (700).



